# Select entries in pandas series based on one part of multi-index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas series constructed like this

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

combos = list(itertools.permutations(['BB', 'BW', 'WW'], 2))

combo_values = pd.Series([2,4,0,2,0,0], combos)
```

So `combo_values` looks like this

```
(BB, BW)    2
(BB, WW)    4
(BW, BB)    0
(BW, WW)    2
(WW, BB)    0
(WW, BW)    0
dtype: int64
```

I know you can extract one entry like this

```
combo_values['BB', 'BW']
```

So I was thinking to extract the first two entries I would like to do something like this:

```
combo_values['BB',]

#or this

combo_values['BB',:]
```

Neither works, and the first option generates the following errors (I am chopping out the traces)

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

KeyError: ('BB',)
```

I know that this alternative solution works:

```
combo_df = pd.DataFrame(combos, columns = ['A', 'B'])
combo_df['combo_values'] = [2,4,0,2,0,0]
combo_df.loc[combo_df['A'] == 'BB', :]
```

But is there a way to do this with my `combo_values` series?

Thank you

Comment: can you consider to replace the index of combo_values with a `MultiIndex`? If it is possible, then slicing kind of the way you tried should work

Comment: This worked perfectly, I just wasn't familiar with `pd.MultiIndex`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use a multi-index, rather than a tuple-index:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

combos = list(itertools.permutations(['BB', 'BW', 'WW'], 2))

multi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(combos)

combo_values = pd.Series([2,4,0,2,0,0], multi)
```

`combo_values` now looks like this:

```
BB  BW    0.25
    WW    0.50
BW  BB    0.00
    WW    0.25
WW  BB    0.00
    BW    0.00
dtype: float64
```

And it can be filtered like this:

```
combo_values['BB',]
```

To yield

```
BW    0.25
WW    0.50
```